# Nav bar on behind pictures when you scroll but i don't want to use z-index

Tags: html, css

My nav bar is behind my images when i try and scroll but i don't want to use z index because i have a lightbox that when you click the image it opens to a bigger image and when the bigger image opens if i have a zindex of 2 then it overlaps the big image in my lightbox. Any help would be great!

**Edit: I tried putting the lightbox to an index of 9000 when my nav bar is zindex** 1 but this happens:

Nav bar above lightbox:

[image]

**I would like my nav bar to be behind my lightbox but when i scroll the images don't go over my nav bar.**

```css
/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
 /** Default lightbox to hidden */
 display: none;

 /** Position and style */
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
 /** Pad the lightbox image */
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 95%;
 margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox:target {
 /** Remove default browser outline */
 outline: none;

 /** Unhide lightbox **/
 display: block;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 90%;
 height: 950px;
 background-color: rgba(155,155,155,0.05);
 margin: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
 width: 90%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: white;
 opacity: 0.8;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 z-index: 0;
}

#nav-bar-portfolio {
 width: 90%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: white;
 opacity: 0.8;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#main-content-index {
 height: 900px;
 padding-top: 80px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

#main-content-portfolio {
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 80px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-text {
 float:left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 display: inline;
 text-align: left;
}

h4 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}

nav {
 padding-right: 20px;
 float: right;
 box-shadow: solid black 100px;
}


nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px;
}

nav a {
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: black;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: 0.2;
}


/* __________________________________________
Main Area
__________________________________________ */

.welcome-banner {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}


#portfolio-button {
 width: 150px;
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: block; 
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 40px auto;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#portfolio-button:hover {
 opacity: 0.3;

}

/* __________________________________________
Footer
__________________________________________ */

#footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: black;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 15px;
}

.div-left  {
 float: left;
}

.div-left p {
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}


.div-center {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.div-center p {
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.div-center a {
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.div-center a:hover {
 opacity: 0.3;
}

.div-right {
 float: right;
}

.div-right ul li  {
 display: inline-block;
}

.div-right ul li a {
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-right: 20px;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.div-right ul li a:hover {
 opacity: 0.3
}

/* Portfolio */

.main-box {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0,0, 0.05);
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.project-icons {
 padding: 10px;
 filter: grayscale(100%);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
 transition: filter 0.6s ease;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.6s ease;
}

.project-icons:hover {
 filter: grayscale(0);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

.project-text {
 padding: 10px;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.project-text-caption{
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">


</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">


  <div id="nav-bar">
   <div class="nav-text animated">
    <h3>Kyle Du Preez</h3>
    <h4>| PORTFOLIO</h4>
   </div>
   <nav>
     
      <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> About</a></li>
       <li><a href="portfolio.html"> Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>


  <main>
   <div id="main-content-portfolio" class="animated fadeIn">
    

    <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link 
    <a href="#img1">
      <img src="http://insomnia.rest/images/screens/main.png" class="thumbnail">
    </a>

    <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS 
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
      <img src="http://insomnia.rest/images/screens/main.png">
    </a>
    -->

    <!-- Portfolio 1 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a class="thumbnail" href="#img1"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/greek-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Greek Alphabet Poster</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Typography</p>
    </div>

    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
      <img src="images/projects/greek.jpg">
    </a>

    <!-- Portfolio 2 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a href="#"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/premedia-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Pre Media Poster</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Large Format</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Portfolio 3 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a href="#"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/mohawkposter-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Hamilton Marathon Poster</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Typography</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Portfolio 4 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a href="#"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/movieposter-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Movie Poster</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Large Format</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Portfolio 5 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a href="#"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/crayola-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Crayola Packaging</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Packaging Design</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Portfolio 6 -->
    <div class="main-box">
     <a href="#"><img class="project-icons" src="images/projects/housebooklet-icon.jpg"></a>
     <p class="project-text">Laing Homes</p>
     <p class="project-text-caption">Brochure Design</p>
    </div>

   </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
   <div id="footer">

    <div class="footer-elements">

     <div class="div-left"> <p> 2016 - Kyle Du Preez </p> </div>
    
     <div class="div-right">
      <ul>
       <li><a class="footer-links" href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="footer-links" href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a class="footer-links" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a class="footer-links" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="div-center"> <p> LinkedIn: <a href="https://ca.linkedin.com/in/kyledupreez">https://ca.linkedin.com/in/kyledupreez</a> </p> </div>


    </div>

   </div>
  </footer>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you change the z-index to a bigger one on the lightbox too?

Comment: when the lightbox opens the background around the image goes black but if my navbar is zindex 1 then it shows above the lightbox background. i tried putting the zindex of the lightbox background 2 but does nothing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context might help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use z-index, 
I think you need to re-order the sequence of DOM. Thus, move your navigation to the bottom, and add `top: 0`

http://plnkr.co/edit/53wQYQmvPR3fcdKfoZjI?p=preview

```
#nav-bar {
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the nav bar is above the lightbox now.